# Setup MAMP & Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, mamp

I am trying to set up Wordpress 5.2.17 using MAMP. but when I visit the wordpress page for the setting I get this message
[image]

Can someone help me with this please ?
Thanks!

So I installed MAMP default configuration and after I paste the folder wordpress that I got unzipping the downloaded Wordpress5.2.17 inside the folder MAMP/htdocs. I create a database called wordpress without any table after that I visit localhost/wordpress and I get this message.

Answer (score 0):

There will be a bit more information needed to help you out.

The following code, inserted in your wp-config.php file, will log all errors, notices, and warnings to a file called debug.log in the wp-content directory. It will also hide the errors so they do not interrupt page generation.

```
// Enable WP_DEBUG mode
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );

// Enable Debug logging to the /wp-content/debug.log file
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );

// Disable display of errors and warnings
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
@ini_set( 'display_errors', 0 );

// Use dev versions of core JS and CSS files (only needed if you are modifying these core files)
define( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG', true );
```

NOTE: You must insert this BEFORE `/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */` in the wp-config.php file.

Also under Windows, the path is C:MAMP\logs -> For MAMP related errors

For MAC: /Applications/MAMP/logs

There you will find a file called **php_error**, there could also be related information to the error.

Please paste the error messages, then the problem could be clearer.

Comment: Thank you so much for you help!
But it shouldn't be MAMP that create the wp-conig when I go on the installation page ? 
This is coming from the error log when I try to check localhost/wordpress: 
PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)